# How to turn off log4j logging

Tags: java, spring, log4j

I work on my Spring Boot app which uses Spring API client as a maven depencency. When I use it in my code, it logs data. How can I turn it off? Where shall I place log4j.properties to actually work? I tried inside resources and also inside folder with my service which uses it.

```
package com.example.demo.service;

import com.wrapper.spotify.SpotifyApi;
import com.wrapper.spotify.SpotifyHttpManager;
import com.wrapper.spotify.exceptions.SpotifyWebApiException;
import com.wrapper.spotify.model_objects.credentials.AuthorizationCodeCredentials;
import com.wrapper.spotify.requests.authorization.authorization_code.AuthorizationCodeRequest;
import org.apache.hc.core5.http.ParseException;



import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.concurrent.CancellationException;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionException;


public class AuthorizationCodeExample {
    private static final String clientId = "";
    private static final String clientSecret = "";
    private static final URI redirectUri = SpotifyHttpManager.makeUri("");
    private static final String code = "";

    private static final SpotifyApi spotifyApi = new SpotifyApi.Builder()
            .setClientId(clientId)
            .setClientSecret(clientSecret)
            .setRedirectUri(redirectUri)
            .build();
    private static final AuthorizationCodeRequest authorizationCodeRequest = spotifyApi.authorizationCode(code)
            .build();

    public static void authorizationCode_Sync() {
        try {
            final AuthorizationCodeCredentials authorizationCodeCredentials = authorizationCodeRequest.execute();

            // Set access and refresh token for further "spotifyApi" object usage
            spotifyApi.setAccessToken(authorizationCodeCredentials.getAccessToken());
            spotifyApi.setRefreshToken(authorizationCodeCredentials.getRefreshToken());

            System.out.println("Expires in: " + authorizationCodeCredentials.getExpiresIn());
        } catch (IOException | SpotifyWebApiException | ParseException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        authorizationCode_Sync();
    }
}
```

This is my project tree:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUMGn.jpg

Answer (score 0):

`logging.level.*=LEVEL`

There are different levels available, the one you are looking for is OFF. So just add the following line into your application.properties file

`logging.level.*=OFF`

Comment: I placed "logging.level.*=OFF" and "log4j.rootLogger=OFF" inside "resources/log4j.properties. It still logs.

Comment: in my answer I was talking about **application.properties file**

Comment: My misreading. Even when I pasted "logging.level.*=OFF" in application.properties, app still logs.

Answer (score 0):

It should be resources folder. But did you made changes inside the file to turn off logs ?
log4j.rootLogger=OFF, Note that this has the highest priority and will turn off all logging.

Comment: I placed "logging.level.*=OFF" and "log4j.rootLogger=OFF" inside "resources/log4j.properties. It still logs.